# Using a user-entered password in a ksh script

Tags: variables, scripting, passwords, ksh

On an AIX server I have a ksh script that prompts the user for their password, saves that password into a temp file, and then uses the contents of the temp file to supply the password for the sudo command that is being run on the remote servers (to run a remote script).
I'm not happy with this approach and would prefer that the user's password was not recorded in a file.

Here is a simplified version of what is in the script...

```
!/bin/ksh

stty -echo
printf "Password: "
read rslt
stty echo
printf "\n"
echo $rslt>./rslt

for svrx in svr1 svr2 svr3 svr4 svr5 svr6 svr7 svr8 svr9
do
print "Connecting to $svrx and getting the StationList..."
ssh -q $svrx /usr/local/bin/sudo -S /home/myuserid/scriptname <./rslt >${svrx}.output.txt
print "Done"
done 
rm ./rslt
```

My question is this; is there a way the script can use the password in the variable rather than reading it from a file as I'm currently doing by utilizing "sudo -S" ?

I don't have the permissions required to install expect or any other software or utils.

Many thanks.

Comment: Your script doesn't do what you think it does; even if you redirect stdin, ssh reads the password from /dev/tty.

Comment: Sorry, Zsigmond.  I meant to say it is the sudo command that the password is being passed to, from the temp file (not ssh as I said before). I have edited my question to remove that error.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd try whis: `ssh $svrx "echo '$rslt' | sudo -S /home/myuserid/scriptname"`

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much, Zsigmond.

Comment: to Zsigmond can you please write it as an answer? so this question will not stay without one.